# Using a progress bar for the output

Tags: python, loops

I'm extremely new to Python and have created a little password cracker, that uses a brute force attack, I'm trying to get my progress bar to output as the program runs, here's what I have so far:

```
import zipfile
import sys
import time


def progress_bar(sleep_time):
    for i in range(101):
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        sys.stdout.write("\r[{0}] {1}%".format('#'*(i/10), i))
        sys.stdout.flush()


def obtain_password(path_to_zip_file):
    password = None

    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file)

    with open('wordlist.txt', 'r') as dict:
        for line in dict.readlines():
            possible = line.strip("\n")
            try:
                zip_file.extractall(pwd=possible)
                password = "Password found {}".format(possible)
            except:
                    pass

    return password
```

So my question is how can I get the progress bar to output while the `obtain_password` method runs? Do I need to change around the progress bar method a little bit?

Comment: You could try having one thread for progress bar and another one for `obtain_password` function. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm Or you can make `obtain_password` function paint the progress bar once in a while.

Comment: @grael That seems a little to advanced for me at this point lol, I like it though, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do won't work, you must keep in mind you have only one thread.

What you could do though, is get the numbers of line in your wordlist, and do the maths. It's surely much more precise than a timer by the way.

I didn't test the code, though with something along these lines you'll have what you want :

```
import zipfile
import sys
import time

def obtain_password(path_to_zip_file):
    password = None
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file)
    with open('wordlist.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        total = len(lines) # get number of lines
        current = 0
        for line in lines:
            current += 1
            if current % 1000 == 0: # every 1000 lines, shows the progress
                print('%.2f %%' % float(current / total * 100))
            possible = line.strip("\n")
            try:
                zip_file.extractall(pwd=possible)
                #password = "Password found {}".format(possible)
                print(possible)
                sys.exit()
            except:
                pass
```

Also I'd recommend you get what are the exceptions raised by `extractall` and catch them properly.
Catching everything like that : `except:` isn't a good practice.

Comment: Could you by chance show me an example of doing it by threading?

Comment: Haha, I could yes, but you wouldn't learn, and your hacking skills wouldn't go up. Give it a shot by yourself, and if you have an issue, post a new question :-)

Comment: By the way, using a thread for the progress bar is useless imho. Though if the "unzip testing part" takes time, then threading could be interesting.

Comment: Lol alright, I'll see what I can come up with thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are to ways of doing what you desire.

1. Let your password-cracker update the progressbar once in a while

   ```
    import time

    # Stores the time between updates in seconds.
    time_between_updates = 10
    last_update = 0

    def your_expensive_operation():
        for i in range(10000000):
            time.sleep(1)            # Emulate an expensive operation
            if time.time() - last_update > time_between_updates:
                print("\r" + (int(i/10000000.0 * 79) * "#"), end='')

    your_expensive_operation()
   ```
2. Use threads

   ```
   import time
   import threading

   # Stores your current position in percent.
   current_position = 0
   done = False

   def paint_thread():
       while not done:
           print("\r" + (int(current_position * 79) * "#"), end='')
           # Make it update once a second.
           time.sleep(1)

   thread = threading.Thread(target=paint_thread)
   thread.start()

   for i in range(10000000):
        time.sleep(1)            # Emulate an expensive operation
        current_position = i/10000000.0

   done = True
   ```

Comment: I don't really understand the threading instances. Can you explain what's going on a little bit please?

Comment: What is this sorcellery ?

Comment: Threads make it possible to run multiple pieces of code at once. The documentation page on stackoverflow should provide you with some code examples. Unfortunately I'm on a train home,  so I can't send a link.